# The order of elements in groups of a particular structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

$\textbf{Assumptions:}$ Let $G$ be finite abelian group and $A = \{a_i\}_{i=1}^m \subseteq G.$ Suppose that every $g \in G$ can be formed uniquely using elements of $A$ as follows:

$$g = \lambda_1 a_1 + \ldots + \lambda_m a_m, \ \ \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i \leq s \text{ and } \lambda_i \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Here we treat $G$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Essentially we select at most $s$ many elements of $A$ to combine together to form $g$.

Furthermore, suppose that there exists a natural number $k$ such the order$(a_i) = k$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}.$ Immediately, we know that for any $g \in G$ that $kg = 0$ as we can simply distribute. Additionally, that gives us that $\text{order}(g) \mid k.$

$\textbf{Question:}$ Is it possible to $\textbf{claim}$ that

$$\text{order}(g) = \frac{k}{\gcd(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m, k)}?$$

$\textbf{Reasoning:}$ Since $\gcd(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m, k)$ will divide every $\lambda_i$, we simply get that every coefficient for each $a_i$ in the sum

$$\left( \frac{k}{\gcd(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m, k)} \right) g = \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{\lambda_i}{\gcd(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m, k)} k a_i$$

is a multiple of $k$. Hence,

$$\left( \frac{k}{\gcd(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m, k)} \right) g = 0$$

as $ka_i = 0$ for every $i.$ That shows that

$$\text{order}(g) \leq \frac{k}{\gcd(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m, k)}.$$

I feel like the uniqueness of how we write the elements of $G$ in terms of $A$ should restrict a smaller order than the claim.

I am having problems coming up with any sort of reasoning that may contradict the claim. I would greatly appreciate any sort of feedback to further enforce the claim or intuition as to why the claim may be false.

Comment: Can you give an example where $A$ isn't just all non-identity elements of $G$ with $s=1$, and $G$ isn't cyclic?

Comment: If $s=1$, then $A$ must be all the non-identity elements of $G$. Additionally, if $m = 1$ then $G$ must be cyclic. Unfortunately, I cannot give you an example where both $s,m>1.$ In fact, I am trying to prove that those are the only two types of groups that satisfy this property.

Comment: I think you can do that without this order consideration. First note that $s<k$, and consider what happens in subgroups $\langle a_1,a_2\rangle$.

Comment: From the uniqueness assumption, it is possible to show k = s+1. Could you be a bit more specific about what to consider with regards to the subgroups?

Comment: Take $g \in \langle a_1, a_2 \rangle.$ So $g$ is of the form $p a_1 + q a_2$ with $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p,q \leq s.$ If $p + q \leq s$ then $g$ has a simple, unexciting representation. So take $p+q > s.$ By the assumption on $G$, $g = \lambda_1 a_1 + \ldots + \lambda_m a_m$ for $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sum \lambda_i \leq s.$ We can set the two forms of $g$ equal and rearrange to get that $(\lambda_1 - p)a_1 + (\lambda_2 - q)a_2 + \ldots + \lambda_m a_m = 0.$ Notice $\sum \lambda_i - p - q < 0$ as $p + q > s.$

Comment: The only strange aspect of the above comment is that the elements of $\langle a_1, a_2 \rangle$ with $p + q > s$ are formed by combinations of other $a_i \in A$ with $a_i \neq a_1, a_2.$ That is very strange and unnatural, but I still don't see an immediate problem with it. Is this the approach you had in mind @SteveD?

Comment: I would continue with this line of reasoning. Note that there are only $s+1\le k$ possible combinations of $a_1$ and $a_2$ (without pulling in other $a_i$). Don't forget each $a_i$ has order $k$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64328/discussion-between-n-geis-and-steve-d).